# How to propely observe sign-in state in MVVM

Tags: android, kotlin, firebase-authentication

I'm trying to observing sign-in state with below code,

```
@HiltViewModel
class LoginViewModel @Inject constructor(
    private val auth: FirebaseAuth,
):ViewModel(){

    fun getUser():MutableLiveData<FirebaseUser?>?{
        return MutableLiveData(auth.currentUser)
    }
}
```

and obeserving it in Fragment

```
@AndroidEntryPoint
class SettingFragment : Fragment() {
//..
binding.apply {
LoginViewModel.getUser()?.observe(viewLifecycleOwner){
                when(it){
                    null -> isSignedIn = false
                    else -> isSignedIn = true
                }
            }
}
//..
}
```

The problem is `observe` detect when `FirebaseUser` became `null` (when signed-out),
but doesn't detect when signed-in.

I don't know why it works like this..

Comment: This LiveData isn't observing anything.

Comment: Since you're using Kotlin, I think that this [article](https://medium.com/firebase-developers/how-to-authenticate-to-firebase-using-google-one-tap-in-jetpack-compose-60b30e621d0d) with the corresponding [repo](https://github.com/alexmamo/FirebaseSignInWithGoogle) or this [article](https://medium.com/firebase-tips-tricks/how-to-handle-firebase-authentication-in-clean-architecture-using-jetpack-compose-e9929c0e31f8) with [repo](https://github.com/alexmamo/FirebaseAnonymousAuthentication) can help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your LiveData will only ever produce one value:

```
MutableLiveData(auth.currentUser)
```

That is, the value of `auth.currentUser` at the time the object was constructed (null).  It's not "listening" to anything at all, and not responding to any changes in the user's auth state.

If you want to respond to changes in auth state, you will need to use an [AuthStateListener](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/auth/FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener), and use its callbacks to push new values into the LiveData.

See:

- https://stackoverflow.com/collectives/google-cloud/articles/68104924/listen-for-authentication-state-in-android